# Getting column values from multi index data frame pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi index data frame shown below:

```
    1                2

panning  sec        panning     sec

 None    5.0        None        0.0
 None    6.0        None        1.0
Panning  7.0        None        2.0 
 None    8.0        Panning     3.0
 None    9.0        None        4.0
 Panning  10.0      None        5.0
```

I am iterating over the rows and getting the index wherever there is a value 'panning' in the panning column by

```
 ide=[]
 for index,row in dfs.iterrows():
        if [row[:, 'Panning'][row[:, 'Panning'] == 'Panning']]:
               ide.append(row[:, 'Panning'][row[:, 'Panning'] == 'Panning'].index.tolist())

print ide
```

If I execute the above code I get the output

```
[[],[],[1],[2],[],[1]]
```

which represents the index where the value is panning

Now, I also want to get the corresponding sec value also like, for example for row 3 for value panning I would like to get sec value 7.0 along with index 1. I would like O\P to be

```
[[],[],[1,7.0],[2,3.0],[],[1,10]]
```

Basically I need the O/P as combination of the index where the value is panning and the subsequent value in the seconds column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
print (dfs)
         1              2     
   Panning   sec  Panning  sec
0     None   5.0     None  0.0
1     None   6.0     None  1.0
2  Panning   7.0     None  2.0
3     None   8.0  Panning  3.0
4     None   9.0     None  4.0
5  Panning  10.0     None  5.0
```

**Looping solution**:

```
ide=[]
for index,row in dfs.iterrows():
    if (row[:, 'Panning'] == 'Panning').any():
        idx1 = row[:, 'Panning'][row[:, 'Panning'] == 'Panning'].index.tolist()
        idx2 = row.loc[(idx1, 'sec')].values.tolist()[0]
        idx1.append(idx2)
        ide.append(idx1)
    else:
        ide.append([])

print (ide)
[[], [], ['1', 7.0], ['2', 3.0], [], ['1', 10.0]]
```

**Stacked solution**:

```
stacked = dfs.stack(0).reset_index(level=1)
mask = stacked['Panning'] == 'Panning'
L = stacked[mask].reindex(dfs.index).drop('Panning', axis=1).fillna('').values.tolist()
print (L)
[['', ''], ['', ''], ['1', 7.0], ['2', 3.0], ['', ''], ['1', 10.0]]

print ([x if not x == ['', ''] else [] for x in L])
[[], [], ['1', 7.0], ['2', 3.0], [], ['1', 10.0]]
```

**Explanation**:

```
#stacked top level of MultiIndex in column
#create column from 1. level of index values
stacked = dfs.stack(0).reset_index(level=1)
print (stacked)
  level_1  Panning   sec
0       1     None   5.0
0       2     None   0.0
1       1     None   6.0
1       2     None   1.0
2       1  Panning   7.0
2       2     None   2.0
3       1     None   8.0
3       2  Panning   3.0
4       1     None   9.0
4       2     None   4.0
5       1  Panning  10.0
5       2     None   5.0
```

```
#boolean indexing
#http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing
mask = stacked['Panning'] == 'Panning'
print (mask)
0    False
0    False
1    False
1    False
2     True
2    False
3    False
3     True
4    False
4    False
5     True
5    False
Name: Panning, dtype: bool

print (stacked[mask])
  level_1  Panning   sec
2       1  Panning   7.0
3       2  Panning   3.0
5       1  Panning  10.0
```

```
#reindex by original index, remove column Panning
print (stacked[mask].reindex(dfs.index).drop('Panning', axis=1))
  level_1   sec
0     NaN   NaN
1     NaN   NaN
2       1   7.0
3       2   3.0
4     NaN   NaN
5       1  10.0

#replace NaN to '' and generate list of list
L = stacked[mask].reindex(dfs.index).drop('Panning', axis=1).fillna('').values.tolist()
print (L)
[['', ''], ['', ''], ['1', 7.0], ['2', 3.0], ['', ''], ['1', 10.0]]

#replace empty lists by empty list
print ([x if not x == ['', ''] else [] for x in L])
[[], [], ['1', 7.0], ['2', 3.0], [], ['1', 10.0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

consider the `pd.DataFrame` `df` in the setup reference below

***method 1***

- `xs` for cross section
- `any(1)` to check if any in row

---

```
df.loc[df.xs('Panning', axis=1, level=1).eq('Panning').any(1)]
```

[image]

***method 2***

- `stack`
- `query`
- `unstack`

---

```
df.stack(0).query('Panning == "Panning"').stack().unstack([-2, -1])
```

[image]

---

To return just the `sec` columns

```
df.xs('sec', axis=1, level=1)[df.xs('Panning', axis=1, level=1).eq('Panning').any(1)]
```

[image]

***setup***
Reference

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = """None    5.0        None        0.0
None    6.0        None        1.0
Panning  7.0        None        2.0 
None    8.0        Panning     3.0
None    9.0        None        4.0
Panning  10.0      None        5.0"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True, header=None)

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1, 2], ['Panning', 'sec']])
df
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I Just want the corresponding sec value for every panning value in the 'panning' column but not the subset of the data frame where the value is panning

Comment: Like in the above referenced dataframe in row 3 i wanted to print sec value 3 for a value panning in the 'panning' column

Comment: @Tinku please edit your post with a mocked up version of what you want.  Use excel, draw something and take a picture, manually create a dataframe, do something to make it clearer what you want.  This post is a good guide on how to ask a question http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Tinku I've updated my post with my best guess of what you want.

Comment: My bad for the question &  apologies for that. Basically I do not need the dataframe as O/p. But need the seconds value may be stored in a list or an array for further processing. I mentioned a sample output in the edited question also

Comment: My bad for the question & apologies for that. Basically I do not need the dataframe as O/p. But need the seconds value may be stored in a list or an array for further processing. I mentioned a sample output in the edited question also

Answer (score 0):

`df.iterrows()` return a `Series`, if you want the original `index` you need to call the `name` of that `Series` such has:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    print row.name
```

Comment: I am getting the index that is not a problem. But along with the index I also want the corresponding sec column value for value panning in 'panning' column.